# how to set default browser for broadcast in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: browser, ubuntu-11.04

```
omnipresent ~/rails $ sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser 
[sudo] password for xxxx: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative x-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/x-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                    Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/Google-chrome   200       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/Firefox         40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/Google-chrome   200       manual mode
```

As seen above, even though my default browser is set to chrome on 11.04 whenever I click on a link from `broadcast (twitter)` the links open up in Firefox instead of chrome.

How can I change so that the links open in chrome.